# std::wstring causes memory access violation (0xC0000005: Access Violation)

Tags: visual-c++, memory, activex, named-pipes

Our application navigates through a list of named pipes and looks for a named pipe created by our application.

If our named pipe does not exist, we go ahead and create one.  However, lately our clients have reported

application crashes at line:

```
fileName = std::wstring(TmpInfo->FileName);
```

You could review the windbg crash dump report that is attached below. The crash is sporadic and not reproducible at all times. Could you help me identify the issue? Is there an issue in converting `TmpInfo->FileName` to `wstring`. Please note that this component is an ActiveX control. Our ActiveX is crashing other applications.

The following code is responsible for enumerating named pipes.

```
typedef struct {
        ULONG                   NextEntryOffset;
        ULONG                   FileIndex;
        ULONG                   FileNameLength;
        WCHAR                   FileName[1];    
    } FILE_NAMES_INFORMATION, *PFILE_NAMES_INFORMATION;


inline void EnumerateRunningPipes(std::vector<std::wstring>& pipeNames, std::wstring stringLookup,      

                                     bool useStringLookup, bool 

truncatePipeDirPrefix)
    {
        LONG ntStatus;   
        IO_STATUS_BLOCK IoStatus;       
        BOOL bReset = TRUE;       
        PFILE_NAMES_INFORMATION fileNameInfo, TmpInfo;              

        fileNameInfo = (PFILE_NAMES_INFORMATION) new BYTE[1024];

        HANDLE hPipe = CreateFile("//./pipe/", 
            GENERIC_READ,
            FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE,
            NULL,
            OPEN_EXISTING,
            0,
            NULL);

        if(hPipe == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            throw CEnumeratePipeException("Could not get handle to root directory for pipes.",
            CEnumeratePipeException::ErrorType::CREATE_FILE, GetLastError());       

        USES_CONVERSION;

        locale loc;
        mbstate_t state = {0};

        while(true)
        {
            memset(fileNameInfo, 0, 1024);
            ntStatus = NtQueryDirectoryFile( hPipe, NULL, NULL, NULL, &IoStatus, fileNameInfo, 

1024,
                FileNameInformation, FALSE, NULL, bReset );

            if (ntStatus!=NO_ERROR)   
            {   
                if (ntStatus == STATUS_NO_MORE_FILES)                       


                    break;              

                std::stringstream sstream;      
                sstream << "NtQueryDirectoryFile error " << ntStatus;

                logger->writeLog(sstream.str()); 
                throw CEnumeratePipeException(
                    "NtQueryDirectoryFile could not get information about the directory or 

file.", 
                    CEnumeratePipeException::ErrorType::QUERY_DIR, ntStatus);
            }   

            TmpInfo = fileNameInfo;                         

            while(true)   
            {           
                const int endStringAt = TmpInfo->FileNameLength / sizeof(WCHAR);        



                std::wstring fileName;

                try
                {                                       
                    fileName = std::wstring(TmpInfo->FileName);//The access violation 

occurs at this line of code.
                    fileName = fileName.substr(0, endStringAt);
                }
                catch (...)
                {
                    logger->writeLog("Caught unknown exception.");

                    if (TmpInfo->FileName == NULL)
                    {
                        logger->writeLog("TmpInfo->FileName = NULL");           


                    }                   
                }

                if (useStringLookup)
                {               
                    if (fileName.find(stringLookup) != std::wstring::npos)
                    {       
                        if (!truncatePipeDirPrefix)
                            fileName.insert(0, L"\\\\.\\pipe\\");
                        pipeNames.push_back(fileName);  
                    }   
                }
                else
                {
                    pipeNames.push_back(fileName);
                }

                if(TmpInfo->NextEntryOffset==0)
                    break;   

                TmpInfo = (PFILE_NAMES_INFORMATION)((DWORD)TmpInfo+TmpInfo->NextEntryOffset);
            }   

            bReset = FALSE;
        }   

        delete fileNameInfo;
    }
```

Here is part of the Crash Dump report:

```
FAULTING_IP: 
msvcr100!memcpy+57 [f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\SELF_X86\crt\src\INTEL\memcpy.asm @ 185]
78aa1ed7 f3a5 rep movs dword ptr es:[edi],dword ptr [esi]

EXCEPTION_RECORD: ffffffff -- (.exr 0xffffffffffffffff)
ExceptionAddress: 78aa1ed7 (msvcr100!memcpy+0x00000057)
ExceptionCode: c0000005 (Access violation)
ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 2
Parameter[0]: 00000000
Parameter[1]: 0d6b8000
Attempt to read from address 0d6b8000

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX: 0

SYMBOL_NAME: msvcr100!memcpy+57

FOLLOWUP_NAME: MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: msvcr100

IMAGE_NAME: msvcr100.dll

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP: 4ba1dbbe

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID: STRING_DEREFERENCE_c0000005_msvcr100.dll!memcpy

BUCKET_ID: 

APPLICATION_FAULT_STRING_DEREFERENCE_CODE_ADDRESS_MISMATCH_INVALID_POINTER_READ_WRONG_SYMBOLS_msvcr100!memcpy

+57
```

Comment: Why don't you call `CreateNamedPipe` with `FILE_FLAG_FIRST_PIPE_INSTANCE` to see whether the pipe exists? This way you will either have the pipe created or know that it exists. "Debugging" your problem will be difficult with what you provide. The whole class of bugs is hard to debug, even more so remotely with little information.

Comment: How are TmpInfo/FileName defined?  Do you have example values for `TmpInfo->FileName` when it crashes?  Is it possible that it's not being null terminated in some cases?

Comment: @luke: write that up as an answer. This is likely it. `UNICODE_STRING` does not guarantee zero-termination. Most native calls such as this one don't either.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see anything in the [`FILE_NAMES_INFORMATION`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540329%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) documentation that says that the `FileName` member is null-terminated. And the presence of the `FileNameLength` member suggests that it is not null-terminated.

So it seems likely that

```
fileName = std::wstring(TmpInfo->FileName);
```

is reading off the end of your `TmpInfo` buffer until it encounters two consecutive null bytes. If the null bytes aren't encountered before it hits an unreadable virtual memory region, you'll get an access violation.

I'd recommend replacing these two lines of code:

```
fileName = std::wstring(TmpInfo->FileName);
fileName = fileName.substr(0, endStringAt);
```

with this:

```
fileName = std::wstring(TmpInfo->FileName, TmpInfo->FileNameLength);
```

That constructor will only read `FileNameLength` characters out of the buffer, so it shouldn't crash. And it's more efficient!

Comment: Your solution fixed the problem. However, I see that the crash occurs at fileName = fileName.substr(0, endStringAt); and not fileName = std::wstring(TmpInfo->FileName); Could you explain why substr could cause a crash? I don't see a NULL termination issue with substr

Comment: I don't see why `substr` would cause a crash. By that point the characters should already have been copied out of `TmpInfo` and into the `std::wstring`. Are you sure that's where the crash is occurring?

Answer (score 1):

How are TmpInfo and TmpInfo->FileName defined? Do you have example values for TmpInfo->FileName when it crashes?

My guess is that it's not being null terminated in some cases, causing `std::wstring`'s constructor to read off into memory that doesn't belong to it.

Comment: How are TmpInfo and TmpInfo->FileName defined?PFILE_NAMES_INFORMATION fileNameInfo, TmpInfo;